# Asynchronous Spring Implementation

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, asynchronous, completable-future

So we have kind of a nasty spring mvc set up where the path of a request is basically:

gateway -> controller -> service -> dmzgateway -> dmzcontroller -> dmzservice -> external gateway

Essentially at the first gateway a user is passing in a date range and i'd like to asynchronously process each month within the range in the controller:

```
@Async
public Response processFoo(LocalDate fromdate,LocalDate toDate){
  List<Response> responses;
  CompletableFuture<Response> response;
  while(fromDate.isBefore(toDate)){
     response = CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(processService(fromDate,fromDate.plusDays(30)));
     fromDate = fromDate.plusDays(30);
     }
  responses.add(response.get());
}
```

This piece of code resides in my first controller and I've used @EnableAsync, created the task executor bean in config, made sure servlets support async but I keep losing these threads.  Keep getting the "use request context" error but its already set in my web xml as well.

I'm just wondering if I'm approaching this problem incorrectly where I should be doing async somewhere else in this flow or what.  Should I expect to lose threads with this architecture?

Comment: The add statement should be in the loop, else you're overwriting the response in every iteration. Also you should use the `plusMonths(1)` method instead of adding 30 days

Comment: @Lino wouldn't adding the get inside of the loop block the whole loop though? would essentially be synchronous again right?

Comment: It would probably be better to add all the futures to the list, and then using a second loop to wait on all